# Conditional formatting: max value, comparing rows with specific data

Tags: formatting, google-sheets, conditional-statements, highlight

I am making an exercise tracking sheet with Google Sheets, and ran into a problem. The sheet has a table for raw data such as day, exercise type chosen from a validated list, and sets, reps, weight, you name it. To find the useful information for analysis, I have set up a pivot table. I want to find the max values for each type of value per exercise.

[image: table]

For example, comparing all the three instances of "DL-m BB" in column D, the table should highlight the highest values between all them: H9 would be the record weight, F5 record volume and so on, and for "SQ-lb BB box" H12 would be max weight and F3 max volume. Eventually the table will have several hundred rows per year, and finding max values per exercise per attribute is going to be too much of a task, time better spent elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Conditional Formatting can be set as follow for the two examples you give above. A separate rule is set for each. They are set from the same cell (H1) adding an additional rule.

Apply to Range

H1:H1000

Custom Formula is

=$H1=max(filter($D:$H,$D:$D="DL-m BB"))

Add another rule

Apply to Range

H1:H1000

Custom Formula is

=$H1=max(filter($D:$H,$D:$D="SQ-lb box BB"))

Place this on your Pivot table page (Try M1 - it must be outside of the PT)
It list max correctly.

```
=UNIQUE(query($D2:$K,"SELECT D,Max(F),Max(G),Max(H),Max(I),Max(J), Max(K) Where D !=''  Group By D Label Max(F) 'Max F', Max(G) 'Max G', Max(H) 'Max H', Max(I) 'Max I',Max(J) 'Max J',Max(K) 'Max K'"))
```

The below query lists the max for F

```
=query($D2:$F,"SELECT Max(F) Where D !='' Group By D label Max(F)''")
```

I have been trying this with conditional formatting and it almost works. Maybe you will see something I don't. Still trying.

This works.

```
function onOpen(){
 keepUnique()
}

 function keepUnique(){ //create array og unique non black values to find max for
  var col = 4 ; // choose the column you want to use as data source (0 indexed, it works at array level)
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var data = sh.getRange(2, col, sh.getLastRow()-2).getValues();
  var newdata = new Array();
  for(nn in data){
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newdata){
       if(data[nn][0] == newdata[j][0] || data[nn][0]==""){
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newdata.push([data[nn][0]]);
    }}
    colorMax(newdata)
  }

  function colorMax(newdata){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[1];
  lc=sh.getLastColumn()
  var data = sh.getRange(2, 4, sh.getLastRow()-2,lc).getValues(); //get col 4 to last col
  for(k=2;k<lc;k++){ 
     for(i=0;i<newdata.length;i++){
       var maxVal=0
       for(j=0;j<data.length;j++){
        if(data[j][0]==newdata[i][0]){
        if(data[j][k]>maxVal){maxVal=data[j][k];var row=j+2} //find max value and max value row number
    }}
   var c =sh.getRange(row,k+4,1,1)//get cell to format
   var cv=c.getValue()
   c.setFontColor("red")  //set font red
  }}
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. There is just one problem: I have, at the moment, 1040 listed exercises with variations included, and even if I trimmed the amount of tracked exercises down, there would still be lots left. I have the exercises listed in a sheet. Is there a way to address them all in that formula? I tried DGET, but it just gave me the circular dependency error with $F2=max(filter($D:$F,$D:$D="liikkeet!a2:q255")) (formula adjusted for my sheet, hence the differences, sheet is named Liikkeet)

Comment: Ah, I copied the wrong test formula. Here's the DGET formula: =$F2=max(filter($D:$F,$D:$D=(dget(Liikkeet!, A:Q, ""))))

Comment: I do not know of a way to put a variable value in a conditional format formula. You can reference a cell in another sheet, but I don't think that would help you. I do have a couple of questions. From your example do you need the max for just column H or for F-K? Have you tried adding a new Value column to your pivot table summarized by Max? That might work for you. If not I can show you how to do it with apps script.

Comment: It would be preferable if it was simple enough to have a max of columns F-K. I tried adding another Volume value column, summarized by MAX, but it just gives me the max of each move on each day, which is rather silly, given there is just a single value to choose from. In theory it sounds simple enough for the formatting function to read what move this value refers to, and then use that piece of string to search for other moves in the same column and compare their values to the originals. The answer could be in the FILTER function's conditions, but I have not been able to figure that one out.

Comment: I'm still looking at this. Could you share your spreadsheet? It might help to see the raw data.

Comment: I got it to work for the volume column: =$F2=max(filter($D:$F, $D:$D=D2)). It highlights the max volumes for each movement, just like it should. I tried using the same approach for G, but for some reason it doesn't work with =$G2=max(filter($D:$G, $D:$D=D2)). Here's the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1if_-fdH_roKZVtNskjrZBWALNe6f3E2d0modjKNNVp8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for sharing the spreadsheet. I think the problem with Col G is using Filter again. I have been trying Query instead. I am getting closer. Put this formula on your pivot table page to the right of the PT (like M1 or you will get an error). This query gives all the max by column correctly.

Comment: Thank you! With the filter function, conditional formatting appeared to work when I just switched the value columns around, but didn't seem permanent enough. Also, at times, it highlighted the wrong values. The filters overlap, and I haven't figured out a way to a have separate columns in the filter range argument. This script is quite good, and perhaps one way of utilizing it could be through highlighting values that match between the query output and the pivot table itself. Although, if max values between different moves are similar, it would highlight them, too, say with reps for instance.

Comment: OK I just don;t think conditional formatting can handle this yet. The apps script posted above does. Enjoyed working with you on this.

Comment: Thank you so much! I haven't tested it myself yet - I have to figure out how to use it in the first place - but I'll get around to it once this family situation of a happy sort is over. Again, thank you, Ed.

Comment: could you tell me how to edit the script, because I deleted a redundant column? The range now ought to be E:J instead of F:K. I though I could do it myself by trying out various numbers in the script, but I have little clue as to what values to alter.

Comment: @kuura I shared a revised spreadsheet with new code
and long explainations to help if you need to 
revise again. I hope it helps.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TeQmtuofrSIVccKD1pAbkO46cJrHPDD-9Ncrx3Y8CYY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You've been most helpful, and with the generous guidelines you've given I'll surely manage and learn something new along the way, as well. Thank you again for your time!